# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk TV instance start fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, tvm

I have an identity TVM on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk that when I try to start it gives

014-07-07 15:29:46 UTC+0100 ERROR Stack named 'awseb-e-ybrpewdr7z-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition. (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: OperationError; Request ID: null)

Now If I go to logs and click snapshot logs all that happens is it waits for a while showing processing but then I get no logs showing up. Does anyone please have an idea what the problem is so I can see either the logs and/or sort the startup problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was  security issue.

Amazon ECB uses a VPC, now that may already be running especially if a RDB has been created first.  Now the groups on the EB instance can show acces rights reuired.  But the VPC has an underlying security ACL that is not group based.  When a RDB is created first that initially created the VPC the VPC instance gets the rights just to access the DB, so will not allow for example HTTP traffic through this cannot get to the EB to set it up.